# Ruby: Insert record on both parent and children with id is set manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My database has a `Product` table with many `ProductDetail`. By some reason, I want to insert some product (each product with list of product details) with id setting manually.

Here is my code:

```
  ::Product.create({
    id:            attributes['product_id'],
   product_details_attributes: attributes['product_details']
  })
```

If I insert without insert product detail, everything works fine. My product record with have id manually. But when I insert product with product detail (id of product detail also manually), I meet some exception such as:

> Cannot find product detail with id = 100 in product id = 10

It looks like ActiveRecord with search inside product with id = 10, and try to update all children for example with id = 100. (But it doesn't exist yet) so I meet that exception.

My question is: How can I insert both father and children table with id setting manually.

thanks

Comment: Maybe, you create product without product details first. then, add product details in next line. ActiveRecord tries to optimize queries, therefore, your query might somehow get problem.

Comment: Why dont you just make a Product.uid = 100? You could do `Product.find_by(uid: 100)`, and you can `add_index(:Product, :uid)` to make it quickly searchable.